# Sign APK file: jarsigner CLI vs Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, google-play, android-keystore

I have a Cordova-based application on Google Play.
The earlier application was signed with Android Studio. So, I needed to update it. I built an APK file with Cordova CLI like this:

```
cordova build android --release
```

I signed it with jarsigner tool, and published it on Google Play. 
It seemed all right, but when I tried to update app on my device, I saw the message:

```
that "APK file is signed incorrectly";
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks and sorry for bad English.

Comment: What version of cordova?

Comment: Cordova version 3.5.0

Comment: I solved the problem by adding this string "-sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1"

Comment: Ah, so it sounds like the default with Cordova CLI was different.  Thanks for sharing your success.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple to do. First of all, you need to have a keystore, for this you can use keytool. After this, create an ant.properties file under /platforms/android folder and add this 2 keys

`key.store=/location/to/your/keystore`

`key.alias=Alias_name`

Here a best description of that http://ilee.co.uk/Sign-Releases-with-Cordova-Android/